# How is たら used as a particle?

Tags: particles

The other day I came across どうたら and while looking it up I noticed that たら is classified as a particle. どうたら is apparently an abbreviation of どうたらこうたら, so I see that it should work for ああ and そう (by the way, what are these called?), but I'm having a hard time imagining how else it is used.

Comment: If by ああ you mean "Ah!", then it's an interjection.

Comment: I mean like ああ (like that)、こう (like this)、そう (like that[?])、どう (like how).

Comment: They are called demonstratives or demonstrative pronouns. In informal terms, they are also called こそあど言葉.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どう and こう replace verbs here. -たら is a particle that attaches only to verbs and i adjectives. It means something like "do this, do that".

Comment: So this is the same たら as the one in [verb]ったら, [adj]ったら? Do you know why it attaches directly to どう?

Comment: I mean, I would have expected it to be こうだったら, sort of like how it is with nouns and na-adjectives.

Comment: どう is understood as a replacement for any unnamed verb or adjective, kind of like blabla this, blabla that.

Comment: It does not mean "do this, do that", but it can mean "did this, and did that". It also means "this and that". It is often used as abbreviation of quotation. `彼がどうたらこうたら行っている` 'He is saying this and that'. Variants are `どうのこうの`, `どうこう`, `どうしたこうした`, `ああだこうだ`, `うんたらかんたら`, `うんぬん(かんぬん)`. They are idiosyncratic expressions, and there is no grammatical reason why some combinations work while others do not.

Comment: @sawa - `彼がどうたらこうたら言っている`; typo

Comment: @istrasci Yeah, you are right. I realized, but could not fix it.